# Accessing a specific bookmark with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

i would like to access a specific bookmark using PDFBox in Java.

I don't find the right method in the class PDOutlineItem.

My purpose is to extract the content of a specific bookmark.

Comment: The question seems a bit vague.  What do you have, using which you want to search a specific outline item?  And yes, I don't think there is any method available to search something directly in the bookmarks tree.  You have to use ```pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getDocumentOutline()``` to get the ```PDDocumentOutline``` object and then use the ```children()``` to get the ```Iterable<PDOutlineItem>``` of child nodes and recursively go inside the tree to find a specific bookmark

Comment: i need to extract the content of a specific bookmark.

Comment: Ok. So, using the above calls that I have suggested, you have to go through the entire Bookmarks tree item by item recursively. For whichever bookmark item you want to get the content - ```pdDocument.getPages().indexOf(pdOutlineItem.findDestinationPage(pdDocument))``` - this will give you 0 based index of that page (first page where bookmark points to).  Then using ```PDFTextStripper```, and 1-based start page number (index+1), you can get the content of the page where the Bookmark points to.

Comment: Have also a look at the `PrintBookmarks.java` example in the source code download. While this doesn't answer the question, it shows a bit more about how this is all connected. https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/pdmodel/PrintBookmarks.java?view=markup